# How to create enum with BiConsumer<R, T> as constructor parameter

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, functional-interface

I would like to create enum class, with BiConsumer as constructor parameter. If I did it like this, everything works ok

```
public enum BiConsumerEnum {

    BI_CONSUMER(((Integer i, String s) -> Collections.nCopies(i, s).forEach(System.out::println)));

    private BiConsumer<Integer, String> biConsumer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BiConsumerEnum.BI_CONSUMER.accept(3, "X");
    }

    BiConsumerEnum(BiConsumer<Integer, String> biConsumer) {
        this.biConsumer = biConsumer;
    }

    public void accept(Integer i, String s) {
        this.biConsumer.accept(i, s);
    }
}
```

But if change code to this:

```
public enum BiConsumerEnum {

BI_CONSUMER((Integer i, String s) -> printString());

// main(), constructor and accept()

private static BiConsumer<Integer, String> printString() {
    return (Integer i, String s) -> Collections.nCopies(i, s).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

The code doesn't run properly and I've got warning: *return value is never used*

How should I extract method from constructor, instead of writing whole lambda inside?

Comment: Your second snippet creates `BI_CONSUMER` with a `BiConsumer` that calls `printString()`. It doesn't call the `BiConsumer` returned by `printString()`.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `BI_CONSUMER(printString());`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes, exactly, that works! Why I didn't came up with this idea earlier, if it is so easy! Thanks!

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I encourage you to move your comment into an answer, which OP can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the fix has been suggested by Sotirios Delimanolis in comments already, yet to elaborate that further your current code representation:

```
BI_CONSUMER((Integer i, String s) -> printString());
```

would compile successfully since you have defined a new `BiConsumer` such that your code's actual definition is now:

```
BI_CONSUMER(new BiConsumer<Integer, String>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(Integer i, String s) {
        printString(); // has a return value, but is it used?
    }
});
```

and do note in the above that the return type of `printString` is not being used. What you possible intended there was to rather use the returned `BiConsumer<Integer, String>` from the existing method `printString` and invoke it as:

```
BI_CONSUMER(printString());
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is the simplest format.

```
BI_CONSUMER(BiConsumerEnum::printString);

private static void printString(Integer i, String s) {
    Collections.nCopies(i, s).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Apprecate an explanation for why I'm being downvoted.

Comment: Please add an explanation of what you changed and why it was necessary.